# Creating a P2PKH address

Tags: address-generation, p2pkh, base58, base58check

I have been learning about how P2PKH addresses are generated so I thought I would try and work through one myself manually. I start with the following public key hash:

`e049ccc9e524a9302c2187bf02c4d78741d9b039`

Which I know should come out to address:

`1MSvmgVJvYkdtCsopFqsT2g3FNNhpcoeBG`

I append the `00` prefix to my hash getting:

`00e049ccc9e524a9302c2187bf02c4d78741d9b039`

I then go to calculate the checksum by converting this to binary:

`1110000001001001110011001100100111100101001001001010100100110000001011000010000110000111101111110000001011000100110101111000011101000001110110011011000000111001`

And then running this through SHA256 twice which gets me:

`a66d4caa10c1b665d6bca3f06788db9fbea6e9912a9fcf8101eb5992f9e8ab78`

I take the first 4 bytes `a66d4caa` and put them onto the end of my prefix+hash:

`00e049ccc9e524a9302c2187bf02c4d78741d9b039a66d4caa`

And I wind up with:

`1MSvmgVJvYkdtCsopFqsT2g3FNNhsp8jXo`

Can someone help me out with where I am going wrong?

EDIT: Forgot to convert it to binary first. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally converted to binary the original public key hash, not the result of prepending `00` (you can tell because it should start with `00000000`). You also might not need to convert to binary at all, many hashing tools will be perfectly happy to accept a hexadecimal input.

The hash you should get after this step is:

```
296b64c7d7e8cf61a327d3e351b9e92e4451af50dff18227550167fe7a13bee2
```

Comment: You are correct I don't need to convert to binary first but I was doomed from the start regardless. I was using an online SHA256 hashing tool and didn't realise it defaulted to treating the input as text not hex. Once I changed it to hex it worked.